# VoIP and SIP, where to begin

Tags: voip, sip

Recently, a client has asked me to do a custom application to manage intercoms (Barix Annuncicom). After reading the documentation, I can do most of the "managing" part, however I am stuck with the VoIP part.

Are there any documentation, guides, articles, that will help me better understand and code a simple VoIP application?

I am looking for a article that has little expectation of previous knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

[voip-info.org](http://voip-info.org), is a nice resource guide if you wanna learn about VoIP platforms and protocols, is mostly open-source oriented and you'll find good articles there.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with [w3c's voice browser standards](http://www.w3.org/2002/09/voice-charter.html) and the [IETF SIP working group](http://tools.ietf.org/wg/sip/).

Answer (score 1):

This reasonably [high-level tutorial](http://siptutorial.net/index.html) has lots of information, including common VOIP questions and a discussion of SIP functions, and book recommendations.

There are more specific tutorials dealing with introductory software implementations (e.g. using Asterisk) on the [SWIK site](http://swik.net/SIP+Tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find details on SIP, one of the best resources is [Tech Invite](http://www.tech-invite.com/).

Other very useful tool is [SIPP](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/) which is SIP packets emulator with easy biult in XML scripting language which allows you to test different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go with either Yate http://yate.null.ro
or PjSIP http://pjsip.org
The code is complete, cross-platform and has lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

PJSIP is a free and open source multimedia stack written in C and it supports audio, video, presence and instant messaging capabilities.It is designed to be very small in footprint, have high performance, and very flexible.

You can go refer other links also as [link1](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Projects_Using_PJSIP), [link2](http://code.google.com/p/ksipphone/), [link3](http://www.pjsip.org/release/0.5.4/PJSIP-Dev-Guide.pdf), [link4](http://www.pjsip.org).

Answer (score -2):

Are you familiar with Asterisk?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Sometimes, the clarification is the answer.